# Flutter: How to paint an Icon on Canvas?

Tags: canvas, flutter, icons, custom-painting

I'm using a `CustomPainter` to draw in Flutter like this:

```
@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  canvas.drawRect(...);
  canvas.drawImage(...);
  ...
}
```

How to draw an `Icon` on `canvas`?

Comment: you mean that [Icon](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Icon-class.html)? if so, you cannot do that

Comment: Yes, I'm about that [Icon](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Icon-class.html). And it is very strange if so (even if the icon is actually not an image but created from TTF font internally).

Comment: its a `TextSpan` see https://www.crossdart.info/p/flutter/0.0.38-dev/src/widgets/icon.dart.html#line-128

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a `Paragraph` containing the code point in the correct font, style it as needed, then draw it.

```
final icon = Icons.add;
var builder = ui.ParagraphBuilder(ui.ParagraphStyle(
  fontFamily: icon.fontFamily,
))
  ..addText(String.fromCharCode(icon.codePoint));
var para = builder.build();
para.layout(const ui.ParagraphConstraints(width: 60));
canvas.drawParagraph(para, const Offset(20, 20));
```

Comment: This didn't work for https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter, but @Ludonope's answer did

Answer (score 21):

@Richard Heap and @pskink based on your answers I was trying and came up with this: Thank you guys this is what I too was searching for.

```
final icon = Icons.add;
TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(textDirection: TextDirection.rtl);
textPainter.text = TextSpan(text: String.fromCharCode(icon.codePoint),
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0,fontFamily: icon.fontFamily));
textPainter.layout();
textPainter.paint(canvas, Offset(50.0,50.0));
```

Comment: is there a way to add a GestureDetector on the icon ?

Comment: 1) If you mean IconButton widget - It has an onPressed function. 2) If you want to add the above CustomPainter add it as a child to Container. This Container's parent can be a GeatureDetector or InkWell.

Comment: You need to also pass the color to TextStyle. Otherwise, you won't see anything.

Answer (score 9):

Just to add a small but important detail, if you are trying to render an icon from an external icon pack (such a Material Design Icons or FontAwesome) you need to add the `package` parameter in the `TextStyle`.

```
final icon = MdiIcons.check;
TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
textPainter.text = TextSpan(
  text: String.fromCharCode(icon.codePoint),
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.black,
    fontSize: size,
    fontFamily: icon.fontFamily,
    package: icon.fontPackage, // This line is mandatory for external icon packs
  ),
);
textPainter.layout();
textPainter.paint(canvas, Offset(x, y));
```

Comment: Thank you this "package: icon.fontPackage" was really the way to go when using icon packages from different source :D

Answer (score 0):

If you have `SVG` file design. You can use [this website](https://fluttershapemaker.com/) to automatically generated `CustomPainter` file dart.

[image]