# Make CupertinoIcon render and not show placeholder

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

Based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57922017/flutter-how-to-paint-an-icon-on-canvas), I tried to draw a [CupertinoIcon](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoIcons-class.html) on a [Canvas](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas-class.html):

```
final icon = CupertinoIcons.add;
TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter( 
             textDirection: TextDirection.ltr 
             );
textPainter.text = TextSpan(
    text: String.fromCharCode( 
             icon.codePoint 
             ),
    style: TextStyle(
             fontSize: 40.0,
             fontFamily: icon.fontFamily 
             )
);
textPainter.layout();
textPainter.paint( canvas, Offset( params.x, params.y ) );
```

Note that the code is fully generic, since it uses properties like `codePoint` of the `CupertinoIcon`.

While this code renders the other `painter` commands, the code unfortunately renders a placeholder of the icon in Google Chrome:

[image]

**How do I make the icon appear?**

Answer (score 0):

The icon appears, as soon as the `package` parameter gets added to `TextStyle`:

```
TextStyle(
  fontSize:   60.0,
  fontFamily: icon.fontFamily, 
  color:      Colors.red, 
  package:    icon.fontPackage  // Need to make the icon appear
)
```

The [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle-class.html) says this:

```
To use a font family defined in a package, the package argument must be provided.
```