# How to use icon from icon class for dot in fl_chart

Tags: flutter

I'm working on fl_chart and would like to use "Icons.favorite" from Icon class for dot.
Is there way to achieve this?
Below is LineChart that I have been working with and I would like to change blue dot on both edge of line to "Icons.favorite" from Icon class.

```
LineChart(LineChartData(
  lineBarsData: [
    LineChartBarData(
      spots: FlSpotDatas, 
      dotData: FlDotData()),
])
```

[image]

I feel like it can be done by FlDotData() but could not find any mategial about and I hope to get help.

Comment: Please update your Question. Are you working on fl_chart? Or with fl_chart? Dot where? How should it look? What did you tried so far? Show your code and what you did so far and some one can try to help you. I think no one will be able to help you like that.

Comment: thank you for point out lack of information.

Comment: I looked up for you. It is not possible to draw an Icon with this package.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. It unfortunate to know that, I hope it will be added in the future update.

Comment: You can build (draw) your own graph. It will help you to learn Flutter better and you will also learn how with this you can learn how to draw a linear a dot (what they are also doing in the package:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jaoJz3q9PmE. Then you have to check how to draw an Icon, here is an stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57922017/flutter-how-to-paint-an-icon-on-canvas. And if you tried but can't get there, post what you made it this far and where you got stuck. (with code and maybe some image how it looks and how it should look.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it said in the comment it was not possible.